# Mongoose find() all json objects

Tags: mongoose

The below code works and is able to find all params for the first JSON object

```
   public async getAllFeaturesByFlagParams(searchFeature: SearchFeatureDto): Promise<FeatureDto[]> {
    return this.searchFeatureModel
      .find({ flags: { $elemMatch: searchFeature.flags[0] } })
      .then((features) => {
        return features.map((flagDocument) => {
          const featureDto = new FeatureDto();
          featureDto.mapFromSchema(flagDocument);
          return featureDto;
        });
      })
  }
```

However, I want to be able to search `flags` and not just `flags[0]`. and be able to return all `searchFeature` that have matching `flags` I've been struggling over this. How can I make this work?

but how can I make the `.find()` work with the array?

flags is just a JSON document

```
flags {
featureFlagId :"124"
name :"exampleName"
}
```

Sample mongoose document return:

for `Features`:

```
[
    {
        "flags": [
            {
                "featureFlagId": "124",
                "name": "exampleName"
            }
        ],
        "name": "exampleFeature1",
    },
    {
        "flags": [
            {
                "featureFlagId": "123",
                "name": "exampleName"
            }
        ],
        "name": "exampleFeature2",
    }
]
```

Comment: try to change this `{ flags: { $elemMatch: { featureFlagId: searchFeature.flags[0].featureFlagId, name: searchFeature.flags[0].name } } }`

Comment: I don't want to just search flags[0], but flags[1-1000] for example. @turivishal

Comment: I updated the post to clarify that I want to change the param that is passed in to an array. @turivishal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you have something like below data in `searchFeature.flags`,

```
searchFeature.flags = [
  { featureFlagId: "1", name: "flagName" },
  { featureFlagId: "2", name: "flagName" }
];
```

You need to prepare array of `$and` operation,

```
var searchFlags = searchFeature.flags.map(function(f){
   return { flags: { $elemMatch: f } };
});
```

Above code will result in `searchFlags`,

```
[
 { flags: { $elemMatch: { featureFlagId: "1", name: "flagName" } } },
 { flags: { $elemMatch: { featureFlagId: "2", name: "flagName" } } }
]
```

Check `$and` condition if you want to match all flags,

```
.find({ $and: searchFlags })
```

Check `$or` condition if you want to match any single flag,

```
.find({ $or: searchFlags })
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cpTeNCPhEL8)

Comment: Been playing around with this for a bit and it always works when there is only one, but does not work when there is more than 1. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: can you show your sample document and expected result from that document.

Comment: I just updated the post with an example document. I included 2 flags because that is what I am hoping to get out of the return @turivishal

Comment: i am not getting that, is that your document you have in collection?

Comment: Indeed. Could it be the "$and" operator messing it up when there are multiple?

Comment: I've played around with it a bit more and it's definitely the $and that is messing it up when there are 2 or more items found.

Comment: updated: I changed it to $or and it worked! Thank you